# Efficiently aggregate results into a Python Data Structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, dataframe

I often find myself looping over some long **INPUT** list (or dataframe, or dictionary). Per iteration I do some calculations on the input data, I then push the results into some **OUTPUT** data structure. Often the final output is a dataframe (since it is convenient to deal with).

Below are two methods that loop over a long list, and aggregate some dummy results into a dataframe. **Approach 1** is very slow (~3 seconds per run), whereas **Approach 2** is very fast (~18 ms per run). Approach 1 is not good, because it is slow. Approach 2 is faster, but it is not ideal either, because it effectively "caches" data in a local file (and then relies on pandas to read that file back in very quickly). Ideally, we do everything in memory.

**What approaches can people suggest to efficiently aggregate results?** Bonus: And what if we don't know the exact size/length of our output structure (e.g. the actual output size may exceed the initial size estimate)? Any ideas appreciated.

```py
import time
import pandas as pd

def run1(long_list):    
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
    for el in long_list:
        my_df.loc[(len)] = [el, el+1, 1/el]  # Dummy calculations
    return my_df

def run2(long_list):   
    with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
        f.write('A,B,C\n')
        for el in long_list:
            f.write(f'{el},{el+1},{1/el}\n')  # Dummy calculations
    return pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')

long_list = range(1, 2000)

%timeit df1 = run1(long_list)  #  3  s ± 349 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit df2 = run2(long_list)  # 18 ms ± 697 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating and then dropping a dummy input column and doing all of the calculations directly in pandas:

```py
def func(long_list):
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(long_list, columns=['input'])
    my_df = my_df.assign(
        A=my_df.input,
        B=my_df.input+1,
        C=1/my_df.input)
    return my_df.drop('input', axis=1)
```

Comparing the times:

```py
%timeit df1 = run1(long_list)
%timeit df2 = run2(long_list)
%timeit df3 = func(long_list)
```

```
3.81 s ± 6.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
5.54 ms ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.19 ms ± 3.95 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Pros:

- All in memory
- Really fast
- Easy to read

Cons:

- Probably not as fast as vectorized Numpy operations

Answer (score 1):

You can directly build a DataFrame from a list of lists:

```
def run3(long_list):
   return pd.DataFrame([[el, el+1, 1/el] for el in long_list],
                       columns=['A','B','C'])
```

It should be much faster than first one, and still faster that second one, because it does not use disk io.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't scale well for large inputs. With 200k columns it is >20x slower than using `DataFrame.assign()` or a solution in numpy.